# Sending multiple headers with curl request

Tags: php, curl, get, header

Hello everyone i was facing a problem in curl request in which i have to send much information or headers in it . I have to set

> User Agent 
>  Sso token 
>  Subscriber id 
>   lbcookie
>  Channel id 
>  Srno
>  Unique id
>  Appkey
>  Os
>   version 
>  Os type
>  Device type
>  Device key
>  Version
>   code
>  Language id
>  Usergroup
>  Host
>  Connection
>  Accept
>   Encoding

i have to send a get request which i sent but it dails and returns unable to handle request or a blank page with no data .

Thanking you in advance
A PHP begginer

Comment: Please provide more information about your question. How you sending CURL request? using terminal? or browser? or any other way? Explain the exact way you sending request.

Comment: Using browser i am sending request

Comment: How can you send CURL request using browser, you are sending just GET HTTP request from browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add your headers to the `$customHeaders` array and see if this works:

```
//The URL you're sending the request to.
$url = 'https://www.example.comp';

//Create a cURL handle.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//Create an array of custom headers.
$customHeaders = array(
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Cookie: PHPSESSID=ciqas3vp82m514iubpr1b0md3o;',
    'Referer: https://www.google.com/',
    // add the headers you want to send as such
);

//Use the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option to use the custom headers.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $customHeaders);

//Execute the request
curl_exec($ch);
```

Refer to the documentation of [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more details